# finding mutated field value

Tags: javascript, mutation

How can I get the `pprice`, `pweight`, `pname` values in to an array?

I cannot get input field values from Javascript because the input fields are created dynamically. I tried to use a MutationObserver but I failed. Please help me.

```js
let tbody = document.querySelector('#tbody');
let addBtn = document.querySelector('#addBtn');
let IdString = "tablerow";
let i = 4;

function creatTableEl(id, pname, pweight, pprice) {
  const createTR = document.createElement("tr");
  createTR.setAttribute("id", id);
  tbody.appendChild(createTR);
  const createTD1 = document.createElement("td");
  const createTD2 = document.createElement("td");
  const createTD3 = document.createElement("td");
  const createTD4 = document.createElement("td");
  createTR.append(createTD1, createTD2, createTD3, createTD4);
  const createInputField1 = document.createElement("input");
  createTD1.appendChild(createInputField1);
  createInputField1.setAttribute("type", "text");
  createInputField1.setAttribute('id', pname);
  const createInputField2 = document.createElement("input");
  createTD2.appendChild(createInputField2);
  createInputField2.setAttribute("type", "text");
  createInputField2.setAttribute('id', pweight);
  const createInputField3 = document.createElement("input");
  createTD3.appendChild(createInputField3);
  createInputField3.setAttribute("type", "number");
  createInputField3.setAttribute("id", pprice);
  createTD4.setAttribute("id", "Delete");
  createTD4.innerHTML = "&#10006";
  createTD4.addEventListener("click", DeleteCells);

  function DeleteCells() {
    const deleteCellIDs = createTR.getAttribute("id");
    createTR.remove(deleteCellIDs);
  }
  return createTR;
}

function addTableRowBtn() {
  let id = IdString + i;
  let pname = 'pname' + i;
  let pweight = 'pweight' + i;
  let pprice = 'pprice' + i;
  i++;
  const tableEle = creatTableEl(id, pname, pweight, pprice);
  tbody.insertBefore(tableEle, addBtn);
}

function Table() {
  for (let y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
    let id = IdString + y;
    let pname = 'pname' + y;
    let
      pweight = 'pweight' + y;
    let pprice = 'pprice' + y;
    const
      constTableEle = creatTableEl(id, pname, pweight, pprice);
    tbody.insertBefore(constTableEle, addBtn);
  }
  addBtn.addEventListener("click", addTableRowBtn);
}

Table();
```

```html
<table class="form-control" name='details'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center ">Name</th>
      <th class="text-center">Weight</th<th class="text-center">Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr class="addBtn " id="addBtn" style="text-align: center;">
      <td colspan="3"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle">+</i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: and here is my html:   <table class="form-control" name='details'>                                <thead><tr><th class="text-center ">Name</th><th class="text-center">Weight</th<th class="text-center">Price</th></tr></thead>
 <tbody id="tbody"><tr class="addBtn " id="addBtn" style="text-align: center;"><td colspan="3"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Comment: Please add your HTML to the question

Comment: Please edit the question to include your HTML. Do not dump it in to a comment.

Comment: How exactly does dynamic input creation prevent you from getting their values?

Comment: you are not even doing anything to try to retrieve the values of those input fields

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the table is dynamically created doesn't preclude you from retrieving the field values. You can achieve this by looping over your `tr` elements within the `tbody` with `map()` to build an array of objects containing the values for each row.

In fact, there's quite a few things you can do to improve your code quality:

- Use a `<template>` element in your HTML to avoid having to write *a lot* of needless JS code creating a repeated HTML structure. Rerieve the template *once* and inject it as needed.
- Move the 'Add row' button in to the `tfoot` so that the `tbody` only contains your `input` field rows, which makes working with them much easier as they are separated.
- Do not use repeated `id` attribute values in dynamic content. Duplicates which are invalid.
- Do not create incremental `id` attribute values while looping through to create HTML content. It's needlessly complex as `id` attributes are not required in order to target the content you need - as the example below demonstrates.
- Put all styling in external CSS stylesheets, not inline in your HTML.
- Use actual clickable elements, eg `<a />` or `<button />`, to trigger events. Don't just attach event handlers to arbitrary containers, such as `td`.
- Use a delegated event handler to bnid a single event handler to all element that require it. You don't need to define a new function in every iteration of your loop

With all those adjustments made, try this working example:

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector('table tbody');
const addButtonRow = document.querySelector('#add-button-row');
const rowTemplate = document.querySelector('#row-template').innerHTML;
const addButton = document.querySelector('.add-button');
const outputButton = document.querySelector('#output-button');

const addTableRow = () => tbody.innerHTML += rowTemplate;
const removeTableRow = e => e.target.closest('tr').remove();
const generateTableBody = () => {
  for (let y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
    addTableRow();
  }
}
const generateOutputArray = () => Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll('tr')).map(tr => ({
  pname: tr.querySelector('.pname').value,
  pweight: tr.querySelector('.pweight').value,
  pprice: tr.querySelector('.pprice').value
}));

addButton.addEventListener('click', addTableRow);
tbody.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('delete'))
    removeTableRow(e);
})
outputButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(generateOutputArray());
});

generateTableBody();
```

```css
#add-button-row {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="form-control" name="details">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Name</th>
      <th class="text-center">Weight</th>
      <th class="text-center">Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr id="add-button-row">
      <td colspan="3">
        <a href="#" class="add-button"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle">+</i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<template id="row-template">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="pname" class="pname" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pweight" class="pweight" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="pprice" class="pprice" /></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="delete">&#10006</a></td>
  </tr>
</template>

<button id="output-button">Build Array</button>
```

Comment: I cannot use any button for calculate/generate array , how can i do it?

Comment: Then put the call to `generateOutputArray()` under whatever event handler you do have access to